# Tish'im Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows two hundred ninety?

### ?תשעים ומאתים - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 290.

Don't spend too much time running after lazy gematria on this one; whatever you come up with will probably be too narrow.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous two hundred eighty-nine entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Avraham to the decent of Yaakov to Egypt 290 years

Proof Texts:

Yaakov was 147 years old when he died and he had lived in Egypt 17 years (Bereshit 47:28) therefore he entered Egypt at 130 years old.

When Isaac was born Avraham was 100.

When Yaakov was born to Isaac, Isaac was 60 years old therefore Avraham was 160 years old. (Bereshit 25:26)

Therefore 130 years of Yaakov's life prior to Egypt plus 160 years Avraham was when Jacob was born equals 290 After Avraham's birth that Yaakov enters Egypt.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.ou.org/about/judaism/bhyom/mar.htm

> The Portuguese Inquisition was abolished, 1821. (Having been
>   established in 1531, it was in existence 290 years.)

Answer (score 4):

[From the reign of King Solomon until the reign of Chizkiyohu Melech Yehuda was 290 years](http://books.google.com/books?id=A24pAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA1-PA134&lpg=RA1-PA134&dq=%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94+%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A+%D7%A2%D7%93+%D7%97%D7%96%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95+%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9D+%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D&source=bl&ots=d-HhI9s8BY&sig=zDuoFbCvRWfmYkMotfqbUHrxDHo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8NomT9mfJKPw0gGYu6nVCA&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A%20%D7%A2%D7%93%20%D7%97%D7%96%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%20%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%9D%20%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%99%D7%9D&f=false)

Comment: Odd; the dates in Seder Hadoros for these two events are, respectively, 2924 and 3199, making them only 275 years apart. (And if it means "from the beginning of Shlomo's reign until the destruction of Sancheriv's army," then that was in Chizkiyahu's 14th year - 3213 since Creation - so it would be 289 years.) I wonder what figures the author of this midrash is using.

Comment: @Alex the Midrash Eser Galuyos; Beis HaMidrash 4:134 also details it as 290 years but I haven't seen it inside.

Answer (score 3):

[290 years from *Arpachshad*'s birth to that of the sons of *Terach*.](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/T0111)

Answer (score 1):

290 are the Petuchot (open Parsha breaks) in the Torah (as counted by [Rambam](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=874)).